# excel documents generate by using liferay

Tags: excel, liferay-6

I am trying to download data from user_ table again similar to my previous post where I want to download data from same table but this I want to print data into excel format. Each and every thing was work fine then I got this error.
I am using liferay 6.1 and mysql 5
error org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.xmlvaluedisconnectedexception 
Thanks 
asif aftab

Answer (score 0):

May be possibility my post are silly but what ever problem I am facing in my coding I just want to share those experience to whole community. May be these are really trivial issue but I want to share.
So I am again giving 
Perfectly working Excel download program

```
   public void adminMethodExcel(ResourceRequest req,ResourceResponse res) throws SystemException, IOException, PortalException
{

    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();                                    //Blank workbook  Excel 2007 OOXML (.xlsx) file format
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Employee Data");                                //Create a blank sheet Excel 2007 OOXML (.xlsx) file format
    int numOfUser=UserLocalServiceUtil.getUsersCount();                                     //getting number of rows or number of users
    int rowNum=0;                                                        //Number of rows
    int cellNum=0;                                                        //Number of columns
    Row row=sheet.createRow(rowNum);                                            //Zeroth row formation(heading)
    Cell cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);                                            //First column creation
    cell.setCellValue("uuid_");
    cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("userId");
    cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("companyId");
    cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("createDate");
    cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("modifiedDate");
    cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("defaultUser");
    cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("contactId");
    cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("password_");
    cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("passwordEncrypted");
    cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("passwordReset");
    cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("passwordModifiedDate");
    cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("digest");
    cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("reminderQueryQuestion");
    cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("reminderQueryAnswer");
    cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("graceLoginCount");
    cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("screenName");
    cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("emailAddress");
    cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("facebookId");
    cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("openId");
    cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("portraitId");
    cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("languageId");
    cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("timeZoneId");
    cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("greeting");
    cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("comments");
    cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("firstName");
    cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("middleName");
    cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("lastName");
    cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("jobTitle");
    cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("loginDate");
    cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("loginIP");
    cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("lastLoginDate");
    cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("lastLoginIP");
    cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("lastFailedLoginDate");
    cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("failedLoginAttempts");
    cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("lockout");
    cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("lockoutDate");
    cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("agreedToTermsOfUse");
    cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("emailAddressVerified");
    cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
    cell.setCellValue("status");
    List<User> totalUsers=UserLocalServiceUtil.getUsers(0,numOfUser);                                //fetch whole table in our object
    Iterator<User> it=totalUsers.iterator();
    User eachRow=null;
    DateFormat df=null;
    String str=null;
    java.util.Date jDate=null;    
    while(it.hasNext())
        {
            row = sheet.createRow(++rowNum);                        //if we are trying to creating a new row which already created, e.g. row=0, and then we again try to creating row on row=0 then we will get an error org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.xmlvaluedisconnectedexception                                                                    
            cellNum = 0;
            eachRow=(User) it.next();
            df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            str=null;
            jDate=null;
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);                            // we have to create column then adding the value another problem that I faced 
            cell.setCellValue((eachRow.getUuid()).toString());
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
            cell.setCellValue(eachRow.getUserId()+"");
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
            cell.setCellValue(eachRow.getCompanyId()+"");
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
            jDate=eachRow.getCreateDate();
            if(jDate!=null)
            {
                str=df.format(jDate);
                str=df.format(jDate);
            }
            else
              str="NA";
            cell.setCellValue(str);
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
            jDate=eachRow.getModifiedDate();
            if(jDate!=null)
            {
                str=df.format(jDate);
                str=df.format(jDate);
            }
            else
              str="NA";
            cell.setCellValue(str);
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
            cell.setCellValue(eachRow.getDefaultUser()+"");
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
            cell.setCellValue(eachRow.getContactId()+"");
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
            cell.setCellValue(eachRow.getPassword());
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
            cell.setCellValue(eachRow.getPasswordEncrypted()+"");
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
            cell.setCellValue(eachRow.getPasswordReset()+"");
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
            jDate=eachRow.getPasswordModifiedDate();
            if(jDate!=null)
            {
                str=df.format(jDate);
                str=df.format(jDate);
            }
            else
              str="NA";

            cell.setCellValue(str);
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
            cell.setCellValue(eachRow.getDigest());
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
            Iterator itr=(eachRow.getReminderQueryQuestions()).iterator();
            Object obj=itr.next();
            str=(String)obj;
            cell.setCellValue(str);
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
            cell.setCellValue(eachRow.getReminderQueryAnswer());
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
            cell.setCellValue(eachRow.getGraceLoginCount()+"");
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
            cell.setCellValue(eachRow.getScreenName());
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
            cell.setCellValue(eachRow.getEmailAddress());
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
            cell.setCellValue(eachRow.getFacebookId()+"");
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
            cell.setCellValue(eachRow.getOpenId());
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
            cell.setCellValue(eachRow.getPortraitId()+"");
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
            cell.setCellValue(eachRow.getLanguageId());
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
            cell.setCellValue(eachRow.getTimeZoneId());
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
            cell.setCellValue(eachRow.getGreeting());
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
            cell.setCellValue(eachRow.getComments());
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
            cell.setCellValue(eachRow.getFirstName());
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
            cell.setCellValue(eachRow.getMiddleName());
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
            cell.setCellValue(eachRow.getLastName());
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
            cell.setCellValue(eachRow.getJobTitle());
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
            System.out.println("Middle val of row: "+rowNum);
            jDate=eachRow.getLoginDate();
            if(jDate!=null)
            {
                str=df.format(jDate);
                str=df.format(jDate);
            }
            else
              str="NA";
            cell.setCellValue(str);
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
            cell.setCellValue(eachRow.getLoginIP());
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
            jDate=eachRow.getLastLoginDate();
            if(jDate!=null)
            {
                str=df.format(jDate);
                str=df.format(jDate);
            }
            else
              str="NA";
            cell.setCellValue(str);
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
            cell.setCellValue(eachRow.getLastLoginIP());
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
            jDate=eachRow.getLastFailedLoginDate();
            if(jDate!=null)
            {
                str=df.format(jDate);                                              str=df.format(jDate);
            }
            else
              str="NA";
            cell.setCellValue(str);
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
            cell.setCellValue(eachRow.getFailedLoginAttempts()+"");
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
            cell.setCellValue(eachRow.getLockout()+"");
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
            jDate=eachRow.getLockoutDate();
            if(jDate!=null)
            {
                str=df.format(jDate);
                str=df.format(jDate);
            }
            else
              str="NA";
            cell.setCellValue(str);
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);

            cell.setCellValue(eachRow.getAgreedToTermsOfUse()+"");
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
            cell.setCellValue(eachRow.getEmailAddressVerified()+"");
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
            cell.setCellValue(eachRow.getStatus()+"");
            //cell = row.createCell(cellNum++);
            System.out.println("Last val of row: "+rowNum);
            }//end of wile
```

The problem was that I am getting the aforesaid error.
Do you know what was the issue, the issue was I tried to create a row which already created by me and that row is already filled by some data. 
E.g. first I created zero row then I add column and keep some data. In next operation again I created zero row and trying to put some value that's create problem.
Thanks
asif aftab